# Cannot get Testflight public link. "No builds have been approved for TestFlight beta testing yet"

Tags: ios, swift, testing, app-store-connect, testflight

My app's current status is "Pending Developer Release". I want to distribute to Testflight before i send it to the App Store, but i get this message in my External Testers group:
[image]

In this same page my current build status is "Waiting for Review"
[image]

Is there anything else i need to do to create a public link? Or should i just wait?

Comment: The message is pretty clear. It is waiting for a review

Comment: Is it the first time you submit your app for testing ? Have it been approved before?

Comment: Its the first time. Never has been approved before

Comment: How long does it usually take to be approved for testflight?

Comment: TestFlight review typically takes 24-48 hours. In my experience it takes longer than App Store review.  You need to add at least one external tester and then submit it for TestFlight review

Comment: I can confirm @Paulw11's post. In my experience TestFlight review does take longer than normal app review as well.

Comment: Yep, you guys were right. It took 25 hours. Thank you for the valuable info